# MongoDB Extended Reference Pattern - Managing Data Duplication

Tags: mongodb

I'm new to MongoDB and trying to wrap my head around managing duplicate data. The Extended Reference Pattern ([link](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/building-with-patterns-the-extended-reference-pattern)) is a good example. When you have two related collections (e.g., Customers and Orders), it can make sense for performance reasons to duplicate some information that would otherwise just live in the referenced collection. So for instance, the Order collection might duplicate the customer's name to avoid unnecessary joins with some queries.

I totally get that. And I totally get that you should be careful about what data you duplicate ("it works best if [duplicated fields] don't frequently change"), as updating those records can be expensive. What I don't understand is how you're supposed to keep track of where all that data is housed. Suppose you do need to update a customer's name. If that information duplicated in multiple orders within the Order Collection, plus maybe one or two other collections, tracking down where all the customer name lives (and the mechanics of changing it) sounds like a logistical nightmare!

Is there some sort of Mongo voodoo magic that can help with these sorts of updates, or is that just a necessarily messy process?

Comment: You could use [change streams](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/changeStreams/) for these sorts updates.

Answer (score 0):

you have to manage all that changes on your app, so you have to take care when select one pattern or another, they are not silver bullets.

and remember not all the data need to be updated, depends of the situation, the data and the context of your app.